# How to create the exact same jobs on each Jenkins master while using gearman plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, devops, gearman

I am using Gearman plugin with Jenkins to provide higher availability. According to the [Gearman plugin document](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Gearman+Plugin) to configure Multiple Jenkins Masters I need to 
1.Install the gearman plugin on each Jenkins Master and configure it to connect to the Gearman server 
2.Create the exact same jobs on each Jenkins master

I am not knowing how to do the second step. Can anyone guide me regarding that?

Comment: there are multiple options available, 1. using JJB [https://docs.openstack.org/infra/jenkins-job-builder/] or 2. using Jenkinsfile [https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/]

Comment: @Bhavik Thank you, but I am still not clear as to what is meant by creating exact same job

Comment: for gearman jenkins job name is a task name. for ex.- if you have job name as 'gen_png_image' on multiple jenkins servers then gearman understans that if it gets multiple requests for 'gen_png_image' then it will spreads those requests on jenkins master whichever has 'gen_png_image'. now "exact same jobs" means jenkins job "name" need to same and "job configuration" it need to be same. also gearman has only visibility of jenkins job name, but it doesn't know what configuration it has, you can make use of above mentioned tool for that. HTH.

Comment: just curious to know for what tool or application are you using gearman plugin?

Comment: I am working on making Jenkins Highly Available and for the same I am looking into gearman plugin as a solution.